# Como retornar o mesmo número aleatório em diferentes sistemas?

Tags: números-aleatórios, pseudocódigo

Um gerador de números pseudo-aleatórios como o `rand()` do PHP e o `new Random.Next()` do .NET irão retornar diferentes valores mesmo **utilizando a mesma semente e mesmo alcance inteiro**, e isso não é o correto para meu projeto funcionar de maneira correta em plataformas diferentes.

Por exemplo, eu compilei um número aleatório da semente **123** num alcance de **1** à **100**, e em **todos compiladores de .NET** retornaram **98** na primeira chamada. Mas ao usar o mesmo *script* em PHP, foi retornado **7**, o que não faz nenhuma ligação com o compilador do **.NET**.

Abaixo, é o código utilizado em **.NET** para gerar o número aleatório pelo site rextester.com

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui, outro exemplo, mesmo código, mesma saída, só que compilado no DotNetFiddle

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E enfim, o mesmo código praticamente, mas compilado em PHP:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E também em C++ isso é ocorrido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para um número aleatório ser gerado **de maneira exata à mesma semente só que em outra plataforma?**

Comment: Criando seu próprio algoritmo. O que você quer não é um número aleatório, é um número previamente determinado.

Comment: @bigown Poderia me mostrar exemplos, fórmulas ou circuitos que ocasionem num número quase aleatório?